# How can I update UI using JSON data that I'm receiving from the server?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, codable

I'm using Swift Codable Protocol and receiving JSON data that I need to put into my labels and images, but it's not showing in my table view when I run the app.

Here's what my code look like

```
import UIKit

struct OfferList: Codable {
    let data: [Int: CarItems]?
    let status: String?
    let count: Int? }

struct CarItems: Codable {

    let id: String?
    let image: URL?
    let manufacturer: String?
    let model: String?
    let price_net: Int?
    let price_old: Int?
    let price_gross: Int?
    let power_kw: String?
    let power_ps: String?
    let milage: String?
    let fueltype: String? }

class OfferVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var viewModels = [CarItems]() {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "http://grandex.de/api/v1/de/offers"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard err == nil else { return }

            do {
                let array: Any = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments])
                print(array)
                if let objects = try JSONDecoder().decode(OfferList.self, from: data).data {
                    objects.forEach({
                        print($0)
                        self.viewModels.append($1)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    })
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print(jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    } }

extension OfferVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id") as! Cell
        let vm = viewModels[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(with: vm)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 130
    } }

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var carImage: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var fuelType: UILabel?

    func update(with item: CarItems) {
        title?.text = item.manufacturer
        fuelType?.text = item.fueltype
    } }
```

I'm expecting it to change my labels, but in simulator table view is empty.
Please advice what am I doing wrong.
Also could someone tell me how can I update image with JSON data?
Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are your data source methods getting called? Are you seeing your `JSONDecoder` printed?

Comment: By the way, I’d remove the redundant `JSONSerialization` call.

Comment: I don't get any error. I've linked data source and delegate method in main.storyboard, and I'm getting JSON data printed to the console. But when I'm running the app it's empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major errors in the structs, `data` is `[CarItems]` and `priceNet` is `Double`.

You must get the error

> Type 'Dictionary' mismatch: Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.

Declare all struct members non-optional and name them *camelCased*

```
struct OfferList: Decodable {
    let data: [CarItems]
    let status: String
    let count: Int
}

struct CarItems: Decodable {

    let id: String
    let image: URL
    let manufacturer: String
    let model: String
    let priceNet: Double
    let priceOld: Int
    let priceGross: Int
    let powerKw: String
    let powerPs: String
    let milage: String
    let fueltype: String
}
```

Declare the data source array without the property observer

```
var viewModels = [CarItems]()
```

Decode the JSON

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
      if let error = error { print(error); return }     

      do {   
         let decoder = JSONDecoder()
         decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
         let result = try decoder.decode(OfferList.self, from: data!)
         self.viewModels = result.data
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.tableView.reloadData()
         }          
      } catch {
          print(error)
      }
}.resume()
```

Make sure that `datasource` and `delegate` of the tableview are connected to the view controller preferable in Interface Builder.

Comment: Hi, Vadian! Actually I'm receiving JSON data and it's getting printed in my console. I don't have any errors. The problem is coming when I'm trying to assign label's text property to certain JSON data key my tableview cell is still empty when I run the app.

Comment: You **must** get errors because the structs are wrong. Please try my suggestion.

Comment: *my app crashed* **where**? Actually my code must not crash

Comment: Now it says
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "priceNet", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"priceNet\", intValue: nil) (\"priceNet\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: My bad, see the fix: `let result = try decoder.decode(OfferList.self, from: data!)`

Comment: It cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Data'

Comment: Please use my code. If `error` is `nil` then `data` is guaranteed to be non-nil and can be safely forced unwrapped. The extra `guard` is pointless.

Comment: Ok, not it's terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to see where the crash occurs (certainly **not** while decoding the JSON).

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad, I just fixed it.
Vadian, you are a such a great help, dude! Thank you so so so much!

Comment: Could you help me with just one other thing? Same way I need to assign image to the each cell. How can I do that?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: Looks like I'm not able to. I've reached my limit. But I asked it in this question. Is there any chance you could help?

Comment: Please look at [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+load+images+tableview)

Answer (score 0):

Add breakpoints in the table view data source and delegate function to make sure that there is data as expected from the server. Also, I see that in your CustomCell, the outlets are of the optional type which should not be. Additionally check the `update(with item: CarItems)` function to see if the label and the expected value exists using a breakpoint.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add below lines of code in viewDid load.

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: I've linked it in main.storyboard

Comment: then have you checked that you are getting data in viewModels array ??

Comment: Yes, it's getting printed in my console

Comment: then it seems your data source not configured. so, better to add above lines of code in view did load first then try if not working then let me share your demo i will fix this.

Comment: I did. It doesn't help